# Error when Binding value to MasterPage (MVC5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

i write a method  BaseController. And HomeController inherated from it

```
 public abstract partial class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            if (Session["GeneralUserFullname"] != null)
            {
                ViewData["Username"] = Session["GeneralUserFullname"];
            }

            base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

After in _Layout.cshtml. I call **ViewData["Username"]** to print name to place set Login. And i have debuged,  **ViewData["Username"]** can get right value.

But it always gives error: ***Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions.***

```
Line 88:                 <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
Line 89:                     <img src="http://placehold.it/300">
Line 90:                     <span>@ViewData["Username"]</span>
Line 91:                     <i class="caret"></i>
Line 92:                 </a>
```

Please give a suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the rendering of your markup is giving you the odd error.  Try correcting the markup for your `<img src=... />` <----- by adding the closing tag.

Comment: it seems that <img> is not relative to @ViewData["Username"]

Comment: thanks. Actually @Html.ActionLink("","LogOut","Home"). I forget to pass linkText in. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the user available for all the views you can use this

```
public abstract partial class BaseController : Controller
    {
           protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext ctx)
            {            
                base.OnActionExecuting(ctx);
                ViewData["user"] = "user";            
            }
    }
```

OnActionExecuting will fire right before calling your action, once you are in the OnActionExecuting function you set the user in the ViewData variable thus available for all the rendered view.

On the view then just print it

```
@ViewData["user"]
```

Comment: I have modified it like your direction. But it does's work. It bring up error:

Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: linkText

it is in @ViewData["user"]

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Comment: @JinLong post your error in the questions, the code I showed up I'm using it in my app, so it will help if you post the error message

Comment: Thanks. It is solved now. Because @Html.ActionLink("","LogOut","Home") in menu Logout. I forgot to pass param linkText in ActionLink. So it bring out error: Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: linkText